# Alternate between groups to even out SQL results

Tags: sql

Hey I'm modifying a forum plugin that displays recent topics.

The problem is that the marketplace threads overtake most of the rows.

Is there a way to sort rows so, let's say, all even rows have a thread that does not come from the marketplace group?

So they are first sorted by the date, and then even rows are filled with discussion threads in the same order they appeared?

Here's what the SQL is returning now, only sorted on the most recent post. Let's assume groups 1, 2, 3 are discussion and groups 7,8,9 are marketplace groups.

| GROUP | Type | Title | Most recent post |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | Marketplace | Selling this | 1m ago |
| 7 | Marketplace | Selling that | 20m ago |
| 8 | Marketplace | Requesting that | 34m ago |
| 7 | Marketplace | Selling this | 50m ago |
| 7 | Marketplace | Selling that | 51m ago |
| 1 | Discussion ---------- | Have you seen this? | 60m ago |
| 2 | Discussion ---------- | Recent news on this matter | 2h ago |
| 8 | Marketplace | Requesting that | 3h ago |
| 7 | Marketplace | Selling this | 4h ago |
| 1 | Discussion ---------- | Have you seen this? | 1d ago |
| 2 | Discussion ---------- | Recent news on this matter | 3d ago |

What I would like to achieve:

| GROUP | Type | Title | Most recent post |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | Marketplace | Selling this | 1m ago |
| 1 | Discussion ---------- | Have you seen this? | 60m ago |
| 7 | Marketplace | Selling that | 20m ago |
| 2 | Discussion ---------- | Recent news on this matter | 2h ago |
| 8 | Marketplace | Requesting that | 34m ago |
| 1 | Discussion ---------- | Have you seen this? | 1d ago |
| 7 | Marketplace | Selling this | 50m ago |
| 2 | Discussion ---------- | Recent news on this matter | 3d ago |
| 7 | Marketplace | Selling that | 51m ago |
| 8 | Marketplace | Requesting that | 3h ago |
| 7 | Marketplace | Selling this | 4h ago |

Comment: Enumerate over type and date, then use this number for sorting.

Comment: *So they are first sorted by the **date*** Please show complete data - `date` column is absent in the example.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: In your result's seventh row shouldn't be it group 8 instead of 7?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be after something like the following; this is an old-school solution, and can be simplified/optimised in MySQL 8+...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table 
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,type VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'Marketplace','Selling this'),
(2,'Marketplace','Selling that'),
(3,'Marketplace','Requesting that'),
(4,'Marketplace','Selling this'),
(5,'Marketplace','Selling that'),
(6,'Discussion','Have you seen this?'),
(7,'Discussion','Recent news on this matter'),
(8,'Marketplace','Requesting that'),
(9,'Marketplace','Selling this'),
(10,'Discussion','Have you seen this?'),
(11,'Discussion','Recent news on this matter');

SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.type = x.type 
   AND y.id <= x.id 
 GROUP 
    BY x.id 
 ORDER 
    BY COUNT(*) 
     , id;
+----+-------------+----------------------------+
| id | type        | title                      |
+----+-------------+----------------------------+
|  1 | Marketplace | Selling this               |
|  6 | Discussion  | Have you seen this?        |
|  2 | Marketplace | Selling that               |
|  7 | Discussion  | Recent news on this matter |
|  3 | Marketplace | Requesting that            |
| 10 | Discussion  | Have you seen this?        |
|  4 | Marketplace | Selling this               |
| 11 | Discussion  | Recent news on this matter |
|  5 | Marketplace | Selling that               |
|  8 | Marketplace | Requesting that            |
|  9 | Marketplace | Selling this               |
+----+-------------+----------------------------+
11 rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to solution from @Strawberry.

Sort all marketplace records by odd numbers in the order, and all discussion records by even numbers in that order.

Afterwards you may order by that expression "sort_order" which would list Marketplace-Discussion-Marketplace etc.

```
select case when type='Marketplace' then
             (row_number() over(partition by type order by id) -1)*2+1 
            when type='Discussion' then
             (row_number() over(partition by type order by id))*2 
        end as sort_order
       ,t.*
  from my_table t
 order by 1

+------------+----+-------------+----------------------------+
| sort_order | id |    type     |           title            |
+------------+----+-------------+----------------------------+
|          1 |  1 | Marketplace | Selling this               |
|          2 |  6 | Discussion  | Have you seen this?        |
|          3 |  2 | Marketplace | Selling that               |
|          4 |  7 | Discussion  | Recent news on this matter |
|          5 |  3 | Marketplace | Requesting that            |
|          6 | 10 | Discussion  | Have you seen this?        |
|          7 |  4 | Marketplace | Selling this               |
|          8 | 11 | Discussion  | Recent news on this matter |
|          9 |  5 | Marketplace | Selling that               |
|         11 |  8 | Marketplace | Requesting that            |
|         13 |  9 | Marketplace | Selling this               |
+------------+----+-------------+----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` in `order by`.  You seem to want one of the following.  To interleave types:

```
select t.*
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by type order by most_recent_post),
         type;
```

If you specifically want to interleave groups 1, 2, 3 and 7, 8, 9 then use a `case` expression:

```
select t.*
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by case when group in (1, 2, 3) then 1 else 2 end order by most_recent_post),
         type desc;
```